# if(isset($_POST['submit'])) coding form action is not working

Tags: php

hi im a beginner in php and mysql here if have a problem, it's either my isset post submit is not working or i have some errors in my coding, can anyone tell me what have i missed in my coding? thank you in advance :)

this is my php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tempahperalatan";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $pemohon = $_POST['namaPemohon'];
    $trkhMula = $_POST['tmula'];
    $trkhAkhir = $_POST['takhir'];
    $n_program = $_POST['namaProgram'];
    $lokasi = $_POST['lokasi'];
    $n_anjuran = $_POST['namaAnjuran'];
    $catatan = $_POST['catatan'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO daftartempah (pemohon, trkhMula, trkhAkhir, n_program, lokasi, n_anjuran, catatan) VALUES ('$namaPemohon', '$tmula', '$takhir', '$namaprogram', '$lokasi', '$namaAnjuran', '$catatan')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and this is my form:

```
<form action="page1.php" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Nama Pemohon: </label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="namaPemohon" id="namaPemohon">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Tarikh Mula: </label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="date" value="0000-00-00" name="tmula" id="tmula">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Tarikh Akhir: </label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="date" value="0000-00-00" name="takhir" id="takhir">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Nama Program: </label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="namaProgram" id="namaProgram">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Lokasi: </label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lokasi" id="lokasi">
        </div>
    </div>              

    <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Dept/Kelab/Anjuran: </label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="namaAnjuran" id="namaAnjuran">
                <option name="1" value="1">BK - B. Kewangan</option>
                <option name="2" value="1">BP - B. Pentadbiran</option>
                <option name="3" value="1">BPK - B. Perancangan Hal Ehwal Korporat</option>
                <option name="4" value="1">BPPP - B. Pemb. Penilaian Projek</option>
                <option name="5" value="1">BPPS - B. Pemb. Projek Sosial</option>
                <option name="6" value="1">UAD - Unit Audit Dalaman</option>
                <option name="7" value="1">PWT - Pej. wilayah Temerloh</option>
                <option name="8" value="1">PWB - Pej. Wilayah Barat</option>
                <option name="9" value="1">KOOP - Koperasi LKPP</option>
                <option name="10" value="1">KSKLKPP - KSK LKPP Negeri Pahang</option>           
                <option name="11" value="1">KSKCIP - KSK LKPP Cawangan Ibu Pejabat</option>
                <option name="12" value="1">IBUPEJ - IBU PEJABAT</option>   
                <option name="13" value="1">KESATUAN - KESATUAN SEKERJA</option>                                    
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="exampleTextarea" class="col-2 col-form-label">Catatan: </label>
        <div class="col-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" name="catatan" id="catatan"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button></center>                     

</form>
```

when i hit submit, there are no errors, but the data are not insert into the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to pass data from form to your php script, you have to remember that the name attribute is assigned for that data to find in php script.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
```

In your button you are not assigned the name attribute. So after post method in php script isset($_POST['submit']) does not find any submit attribute. So it returns false.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
```

So you have to use this line for button.

Answer (score 2):

Always remember that it is the  name attribute that links your form to your php script. Thus it should be:

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` this is not working why because you have not provided name of the submit button `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>`

add name of submit button like below.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
```

OR

`if (isset($_POST)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if `$_POST` isn't empty

```
if(!empty($_POST)) // form has been submitted
```

You have no form input with name `submit` in your case

Answer (score 0):

Hi give name for the button as following

```
<center><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button></center>
```

this will work